# how to fix input from being returned backwards

Tags: javascript, while-loop

For some reason when enter input its being returned in reverse. I can get it to work using a for loop, but how would I do this using a while loop?

```
 var input = document.getElementById('userinput').value;
 var i  = input.length;
 while (i--) {

    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML += input[i] + "<br/>";

  }
```

Comment: use a for loop?

Comment: I understand that's the simplest approach, but is there a way to do it using a while loop?

Comment: your example is using a while loop? what else you after.

Comment: `var i = 0; while (i < input.length) { code ...; i++ }`

Comment: while loop as is, then do: `var el = document.getElementById('message');` outside the loop, and inside  `el.innerHTML = input[i] + "<br/>" + el.innerHTML;` - there's other ways too ...

Comment: Your code is saying, start from the last index and go down until it's 0, did you even attempt to reverse the logic? Sorry, but it's hard to understand what you're having a hard time with

Answer (score 2):

Either reverse the loop counter and condition:

```
var input = document.getElementById('userinput').value;
var i = 0;
while (i < input.length) {
  document.getElementById('message').innerHTML += input[i] + "<br/>";
}
```

Or reverse the order of concatenation inside the loop:

```
var input = document.getElementById('userinput').value;
var i  = input.length;
while (i--) {
  document.getElementById('message').innerHTML =
          input[i] + "<br/>" + document.getElementById('message').innerHTML;
}
```

Note that either way you shouldn't update `.innerHTML` in a loop: as a general principle try to minimise DOM updates, so use a temporary variable to build up the desired string and then assign `.innerHTML` once *after* the loop. Or for what you're actually doing here you don't need a loop:

```
var input = document.getElementById('userinput').value;
document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = input.split("").join("<br>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to achieve your goal:

```
var input = document.getElementById('userinput').value;
document.getElementById('message').innerHTML += input.split('').join('<br/>')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different approach using split and forEach

```
var input = document.querySelector("#userinput").value;
var html = "";

input.split("").forEach(function(char){

  html += char + "<br>";

});

document.querySelector("#message").innerHTML = html;
```